# Is it possible to have two init in an ObservableObject class?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, observableobject

I have created an `ObservableObject` object class, and I need to create 2 inits one with passing a string parameter and another without passing.

```
class DictionaryModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var dbName: String = ""
    private var dbQueue: DatabaseQueue!
    var localDBFile: String

//this `init` works fine:

init(_ localDBName: String) {
        self.localDBFile = localDBName
        var config = Configuration()
        config.readonly = false
        guard let dbPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: localDBName, ofType: "sqlite") else { return }
        do {
            self.dbQueue = try DatabaseQueue(path: dbPath, configuration: config)
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

}

for the second init I need to change `@Published var dbName` on different occasions, for example when user choose another database. I need this changing `dbName` to affects on all views like bookmark, searching and etc..

```
init() {
    var config = Configuration()
    config.readonly = false
    let documentDirectoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let dbPath = documentDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("\(dbName).sqlite").path
    
    do {
        self.dbQueue = try DatabaseQueue(path: dbPath, configuration: config)
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    fetchBookmarks()
}
```

I keep getting this error `self' used in property access 'dbName' before all stored properties are initialized`. Is there any way to have two inits in one class one with passing parameter and another without any?

Comment: In the second initializer, where do you intend the value of `dbName` to come from?

Comment: @Alexander I am trying to change it with button or something similar

Comment: An initialiser needs to set _initial_ values. Without that, how would the `DictionaryModel` behave before you've given it any `dbName` values from the UI? It needs to do _something_. More than likely, what you want is for your UI layer to hold onto a `DictionaryModel?`, and only initialize it with a value once the user has given you a DB name. Then, if the user wants to disconnect (you nil out that variable) and connect to another DB name, you create a new `DictionaryModel` object at that time, and replace the previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to have two inits in one class one with passing parameter and another without any?

Absolutely. But you cannot violate the rules: you cannot, as the error message tells you, "access `dbName` before all stored properties are initialized." And what stored properties are there? `localDBFile`. You *must* set `localDBFile` to *something* — and you are not doing that. Even if you just set it to an empty string, you *must* set it to *something*.

Moreover, your declaration `private var dbQueue: DatabaseQueue!` is a really bad idea. Exclamation mark means "crash me". This is an accident waiting to happen.